# How to disable "'variable' undeclared (first use in this function)" warning in RHIDE (DJGPP)

Tags: c, dos, djgpp

I have an old C program (which I didn't write) which worked for me before on a machine I had using DJGPP with RHIDE under DOS.

The problem is, that since I've moved to a new machine, when I try and compile it, I get loads (100s) of `"'variable' undeclared (first use in this function)"` warnings.

I don't have the time to go back over this and amend the code at the minute... is there a way to disable this warning and let me build?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Sorry guys, this isn't my area at all. The following code:

```
char *sbname;
sbname = calloc (99, sizeof(char));
```

The second line produces an error of:

```
Error: 'sbname' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

This hadn't produced any errors on the last machine, so I assumed there is a setup issue.

Thanks

Comment: *Warnings* shouldn't stop you building the code. Do you mean *errors* ? Can you give an example code fragment that results in an error, along with the actual error message ?

Comment: Those are errors not warnings. You need to fix them to compile your program. Sometimes something trivial like missing `;` can cause lots or errors. Focus on first reported error. It's probably causing the rest.

Comment: are these lines consecutive? are they actually inside a function? can you put them in a separate source file, inside a function, and try to compile it?

Comment: @n.m. - yes, they're consecutive and inside a function.

Comment: Hmm, odd! Do you get any other errors, or is it just that? (Could you post a bit more code?).

Comment: (And I'm not sure it's relevant, but are there any .h files being included, for example?)

Comment: Could it be that you have CRLF issues here? DOS using CRLF, Mac using CR only and the compiler being picky?